# Line bot keeps returning invalid reply token

Tags: line, bots

I am trying to make line bot using this github:
 https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php
But when I try to run, it keeps returning invalid reply token.
A lot of tutorial said that I need to verify my webhook, but I have already verified and it show success. I have already tried to read a lot of tutorial but they never got this problem. Anyone here know why?
Do i need to make another php file for webhook function?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe your channel secret and token reverse?

Answer (score 0):

Not only webhook , but also need to make sure you already have the permission for replying message , have you check the @Line control panel like the following image

[image]